# How do I convert a bytestring to a numeric value in Python?

Tags: python, opc-ua

The byte string I read from the ExtensionObject node on the opcua server side is[image: bytestrings] how do I convert it to a decimal, this is the result of parsing one of the bytestrings according to the struct module in python.[image: one of these] [image: result]
This is obviously wrong, what am I supposed to do about it, the data I got was something like this
[image]
This is my code:

```
import struct
# Example byte string containing double values
byte_string = b'\x84^\x05\x00\x00\xf7\n\x19\n\....'
# Determine the size of a double in bytes
double_size = struct.calcsize('!d')

# Calculate the number of double values in the byte string
num_values = len(byte_string) // double_size

# Loop through the byte string and unpack double values
for i in range(num_values):
    # Calculate the offset for the current double value
    offset = i * double_size
    # Unpack the double value from the byte string
    double_value = struct.unpack_from('!d', byte_string, offset)[0]
    print(double_value)
```

If someone has advices,thank you inadvance.

Comment: Do you know the binary structure of the data? Is there one or multiple values per byte string? Please post one full byte string and the expected result from it if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score -1):

As @ivvija commented, if you know the binary structure of the data upfront, you can write code to decode the extension object. To find out the structure, use an OPC UA client such as UaExpert, and read the DataTypeDefinition attribute of the node you are reading the Value/subscribing to a Value.

A general solution, i.e. if you have multiple data types, or the data types are not known upfront, is to use an OPC UA client library than can interpret the DataTypeDefinition (or data type dictionary - an older approach in OPC UA), and give you the decoded data already. An example of this is here: https://github.com/OPCLabs/Examples-QuickOPC-Python/blob/main/CPython/Console/UADocExamples/ComplexData/Net._GenericData.DataTypeKind1.Main1.py .